# Correct function using Math.random() to get 50/50 chance

Tags: javascript

Which is the correct function for getting a precise 50/50 chance:

```
return Math.random() < 0.5;
```

Vs

```
return Math.random() <= 0.5;
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'precise'? Should running the function 10 times return 5 x `true` and 5 x `false` values?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The first one is the correct because the random number generators returns a number from 0 to 0.99999999 (depends on the exact accuracy of the generator itself)

So by splitting the values into two groups using the "<" operator, you should get two equal ranges:

[0 upto 0.49999999] and [0.5 upto 0.9999999]

Comment: When I run `Math.random()`, *sometimes* it returns a number from one group multiple times in a row, however running it several times will *eventually* produce 50/50 result. But how many times?

Answer (score 37):

[`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random):

> The Math.random() function returns a floating-point, pseudo-random number in the range [0, 1); that is, from 0 (inclusive) up to but not including 1 (exclusive)

The random number is either in the range `[0,0.5)` or `[0.5,1)`. So you should use `return Math.random() < 0.5;` to have a (theoretical) 50/50 chance.